# How to avoid duplicated devices on debug list on firebase?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, debugging

I am working with the firebase logevent debug view.

A couple days ago it starting showing duplicated devices on the list. Attached is an image of how it looks. any help or suggestion on what to look for would be great, thanks

[image: duplicated devices image]

Comment: Thnaks for the comment. I think there is no token needed for analytics. I do not use any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for different development enviroments such as qa or production